# Professional way to word option to relinquish creative discretion

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests

What would be a professional way when gathering information from a client for a design gig to phrase an option to leave the specified element up to designers creative discretion?

Comment: This seems to be a legal question; you might have better luck asking on law.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Having done that for years I assure you there's no specific term, nor anything much like one.

You might talk about how tightly a brief is defined, how closely a project is specified or what degree of freedom the designer has… and please look at how hard it would be to re-phrase or to measure any of those terms…

Comment: Looking again, I also think *to relinquish creative discretion* doesn't fit there, at all, quite apart from the fact that *discretion* here is almost opposite to the *control* you seem to mean.

Further, the relinquishing would normally apply when, eg, an author sold his work to a publisher or film-maker and retained no control over what happened to it, which is hugely different.